# Concatenate two arrays element with all possible combinations

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a hive table with

```
| row                         | column                     |
| --------------------------- | ---------------------------|
| null                        | ["black", "blue", "orange"] 
| ["mom", "dad", "sister"]    | ["amazon", "fiipkart", "meesho", "jiomart", ""]
```

Using Spark SQL, I would like to create a new column with an array of all possible combinations:

```
| row                         | column          | output                            |
| ---------------------------|------------------|-----------------------------------|
| null                       |["b", "s", "m"]   |["b", "s", "m"]                    |
| ["1", "2"]                 |["a", "b",""]     |["1_a", "1_b","1","2_a", "2_b","2"]|
```

Comment: Did any of the solutions worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to implement this:

1. The first way includes `array` transformations:

```
df
  // we first make your null value as an empty array
  .withColumn("row", when(col("row").isNull, Array("")).otherwise(col("row")))
  // we create an array of 1s that is equal to the multiplying of row size and column size
  .withColumn("repeated", array_repeat(lit(1), size(col("row")) * size(col("column"))))
  // we create indexes according to the sizes
  .withColumn("indexes", expr("transform(repeated, (x, i) -> array(i % size(row), i % size(column)))"))
  // we concat the elements
  .withColumn("concat", expr("transform(indexes, (x, i) -> concat_ws('_', row[x[0]], column[x[1]]))"))
  // we remove underscores before and after the name (if found)
  .withColumn("output", expr("transform(concat, x -> regexp_replace(x, '(_$)|(^_)', ''))"))
```

Output:

```
+------+---------+------------------+------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
|row   |column   |repeated          |indexes                                         |concat                      |output                    |
+------+---------+------------------+------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
|[]    |[b, s, m]|[1, 1, 1]         |[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]]                        |[_b, _s, _m]                |[b, s, m]                 |
|[1, 2]|[a, b, ] |[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]|[[0, 0], [1, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [0, 1], [1, 2]]|[1_a, 2_b, 1_, 2_a, 1_b, 2_]|[1_a, 2_b, 1, 2_a, 1_b, 2]|
+------+---------+------------------+------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+--------------------------+
```

2. The second way includes `explode` and other functions:

```scala
df
  // we first make your null value as an empty array
  .withColumn("row", when(col("row").isNull, Array("")).otherwise(col("row")))
  // we create a unique ID to group by later and collect
  .withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
  // we explode the columns and the rows
  .withColumn("column", explode(col("column")))
  .withColumn("row", explode(col("row")))
  // we combine the output with underscores as separators
  .withColumn("output", concat_ws("_", col("row"), col("column")))
  // we group by again and collect set
  .groupBy("id").agg(
    collect_set("row").as("row"),
    collect_set("column").as("column"),
    collect_set("output").as("output")
  )
  .drop("id")
  // we replace whatever ends with _ and starst with _ (_1, or 1_)
  .withColumn("output", expr("transform(output, x -> regexp_replace(x, '(_$)|(^_)', ''))"))
```

Final output:

```
+------+---------+--------------------------+
|row   |column   |output                    |
+------+---------+--------------------------+
|[1, 2]|[b, a, ] |[2, 1_a, 2_a, 1, 1_b, 2_b]|
|[]    |[s, m, b]|[s, m, b]                 |
+------+---------+--------------------------+
```

I left other columns in case you want to see what is happening, good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the solution! Multi step transformations using Dataframe API is definitely a possibility here but I am looking for more elegant way of doing this in Spark SQL without writing complicated subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

One straight forward and easy solution is to use a custom UDF function:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf, col

def combinations(a, b):
  c = []
  for x in a:
    for y in b:
      if not x: 
        c.append(y)
      elif not y:
        c.append(x)
      else:
        c.append(f"{x}_{y}")
  return c

udf_combination = udf(combinations)

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    [["1", "2"], ["a", "b", ""]]
], ["row", "column"])

df.withColumn("res", udf_combination(col("row"), col("column")))

# +------+--------+--------------------------+
# |row   |column  |res                       |
# +------+--------+--------------------------+
# |[1, 2]|[a, b, ]|[1_a, 1_b, 1, 2_a, 2_b, 2]|
# +------+--------+--------------------------+
```